# Sharepoint CSS issue

Tags: 2007

We have custom master page for the site. WE have to use custom master page in the site.  When we try to render list items in a webpart some of the list item columns are truncated.This problems can be solved by using IE8. But departments across the organisation are not upgraded to IE 8.

I have to use IE 6 to solve this problem. Any ideas from any body.

Hari Gillala

Answer (score 1):

Hari:

The problem is, as you indicate, the CSS you have in place in your master page. Your question is pretty non-specific, since you haven't described what any of the customizations actually are. It's going to take some debugging. Try backing out the CSS entirely and adding in the pieces one by one. Odds are the problem is with the ms-vb class, though (all depending on what your customizations are).

M.

Comment: Hi Mark,  I have created a page using custom master page. In the page I have used custom list and done some validation on those using javascript. 

I can see all the list item heading but not the values at the right hand side, where the values are being truncated.

Comment: Well, like I said before, it's probably your CSS. However, if you've added script, that could be causing the problem, too. Best step is to strip things back to the point where you see things correctly and then layer them back in step by step.

Comment: Hi Mark, Its organisation website and all the other sites are using same master page. How can i do the changes without effecting the other sites.?